# Redirecting to home page after login conflicts with removing protected routes for logged in users | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the react router implemented to protect (hide) the routes such as login and signup for logged in users, this however causes a problem when redirecting to the homepage after login, the page (route) is removed from the routes before the code reaches where it should push the homepage, eventually causing a blank page on login, and no redirection occurs.

Routes

```
        <Switch>
          {Auth()}
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} key={3} />
        </Switch>
```

Auth()

```
export default function Auth() {
  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (user) return [];

  return [
    <Route path={"/login"} exact component={Login} key={1} />,
    <Route path={"/signup"} exact component={Register} key={2} />,
  ];
}
```

On login

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      return history.push("/");
    }
  }, [success, dispatch, history]);
```

Here, I can't guarantee this code is run before the routes being removed from the stack.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `history.push` but rather a `<Redirect to="/" />` in a `<Switch>` from react-router. So after login, your login/signup routes will be unmount, and current route will fallback to your `<Redirect>`

Comment: why are you returning history.push()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has lots of bad practices.

however if I were you I would change my files to something like this:

Routes

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
   return(
       <Switch>
          {user && <Auth />}
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} key={3} />
        </Switch>
)
```

Auth

```
export default function Auth() {
  return (
    <Route path={"/login"} exact component={Login} key={1} />,
    <Route path={"/signup"} exact component={Register} key={2} />,
  );
}
```

login

```
if (loginSuccess){
     return (
         <Redirect to="/" />
     )
}else{
    return (
         //implementation of  login form
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what bad practices can you see?

Comment: so as you use keys in your route I assume that you use react router 3 or sooner, so it should be an old code!
but I changes your code to be semantically better. not returning arrays or using function in `jsx` instead of declare it as compoenent are among them.

Comment: but let's focus on your code! could you make it work?